# What is this buttercup "like" flower?

Tags: identification

Can you tell me what this is please? I tried searching for general descriptions online but I couldn't find anything.  The plant without any flowers looks to me to be the same type.  I only read about daffodils without flowers being termed as "blind" this year, maybe that is something that various plants can do too.

[image: Buttecup like yellow flowers]
[image: Buttecup like - Whole with flowers]
[image: Buttecup like - Whole with no flowers]

EDIT: 
I had used a link to flickr before SE used imgur.com for hosting images. I think I'd moved the images around in flickr which broke the url.  I couldn't find a way to figure out which images I'd originally got posted in this question.  I'm quite certain it was these three.  You can find these and other flower images on my [flickr account](https://www.flickr.com/search/?tag_mode=all&sort=relevance&user_id=92157978%40N06&tags=flower&view_all=1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the Marsh Marigold or [Caltha palustris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caltha_palustris) which is blooming in my garden right now.  This plant is extremely happy to sit in water or water logged soil. It is not troubled by any pests in my water garden.  The reference indicates that it gets over 80 cm tall but mine are much less than that at around 10 to 15 cm.  They are not aggressive spreaders and do quite well in full sun if they have adequate access to water.

Answer (score -1):

It is definitely a ranuncluoid, but I can't go any further.

Comment: Thanks, That's understandable when there are so many species (about 600 according to the Wikipedia article).

Comment: Sorry, I've had to take the accept off this answer.  I don't recall if I looked up the name before or not.  The other answer of Marsh Marigold or Caltha palustris looks much closer.

Comment: The Caltha palustris Wikipedia page has the family Ranunculaceae so I think you had the right idea but mis-typed the name maybe.